# DataGridView bitmap scaling wrong when resetting sorting

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bitmap

Hello I got a (hopefully small) problem with DataGridview and it's sorting.

I'm reading an csv and add them to a DGV line by line in that order they appear in the csv. It is just one string and a filename to a bitmap.
I add the string in the first cell of an row and load the bitmap which I add to the second cell. Bitmaps are looking fine.
Let's call that 'chronologically' sorted.

Now what I wanted to do is:

1. User can sort them by clicking the column head
2. When performing a right click a contex menu comes up and the user can choose to remove the sorting. Now the table should look like before ('chronological')

The sorting itself by using the column head works fine.
Now I ran into two problems, either the sorting will not be removed, even when I re-read all lines of the csv.
Or the chronological order is reapplied but the bitmap scaling is off.

So this is what I've done:

```
DataTable DT = new DataTable("DT_Results");
DataSet DS = new DataSet("DS_Results");

DS.Tables.Add(DT);

//Adding the dataset to the DataGridView
DGV.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
DGV.DataSource = DS;
DGV.DataMember = "DT_Results";

...
DataRow dr = DT.NewRow();
dr["User"] = UserName;
dr["UserImage"] = UserImage;
DT.Rows.Add(dr)
```

The context menu has one item which calls

```
private void ReloadTable(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DGV.DataSource = DT;  
}
```

This removes the custom sorting but the bitmaps are resized and look ugly.
I would be glad if someone can give me a hint.

Comment: You could generate your own thumbnails in advance with the exact required size... then scaling shouldn't be an issue. How exactly are you reading the images, though? Images should be handled very carefully; they need to be disposed when no longer used to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Do you have any scaling in your code? How do you set the row heights? Sort tends to mess up these..